# vue3 + vee-validate - handleSubmit doesn't return values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate

I'm using the newest vue@3.1.2 with Composition API. I want to use current vee-validate@4.4.5 accordingly to their documentation. But when `handleSubmit` is used nothing works as I expect.

```html
<form @submit="onSubmit">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="edit-email" class="form-label">E-mail</label>
    <input
      id="edit-email"
      name="email"
      class="form-control"
      v-model="email"
      type="text"
      />
    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ emailError }}</div>
  </div> 

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button> 
</form>
```

```js
import { useField, useForm } from "vee-validate";
import { object, string } from "yup";

export default {
  name: "App",
  setup() {
    const { handleSubmit } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = handleSubmit((values) => { 
      console.log(values, submitCount.value); // values is empty: {}
    });

    const schema = object({
      email: string().required().email(),
    });

    useForm({
      validationSchema: schema,
      initialValues: {
        email: "",
      },
    });

    const { value: email, errorMessage: emailError } = useField("email");

    return {
      email,
      emailError, 
      onSubmit,
    };
  },
};
```

Reproduced problem:

**https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-vee-validate-handlesubmit-with-no-values-oj0ot?file=/src/App.vue**

---

Documentation:

https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/composition-api/handling-forms#javascript-submissions-ajax

And I have two problems:

1. Why submit doesn't invoke `validate()` for the form and as result doesn't prevent submit when they're mistakes?
2. Why in the `handleForm` callback argument `values` is empty?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've created a working solution but using Form, Field components: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-vee-validate-form-field-klq81?file=/src/App.vue. But I'd like to find the answer to why my first approach doesn't work.

Comment: The same problem. `handleForm` callback arguments are empty. Did you find solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your first example does not work because you are using `useForm` twice and you have to use it once

I've tested this code on your example and it worked for me

```js
let response = ref("Empty.");

    const schema = object({
      email: string().required().email(),
      password: string().required().min(4),
    });

    const { errors: formErrors, handleSubmit, setFieldError, submitCount } = useForm({
      validationSchema: schema,
      initialValues: {
        email: "",
        password: "",
      },
      // validateOnMount: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly for me the order of `useForm` / `useField` calls mattered: when `useField` call goes first and `useForm` follows - `values` are empty. When I place `useForm` at the first place - values are no longer empty.